# Magento 1.9 multi stores with independent carts

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Is it possible to have an independent cart for each store under a single Magento installation? Now I have created a site with 2 stores, but each store is sharing the single cart. How it is possible to have an independent cart for each of my stores.

An example site is https://www.usinger.com/

Answer (score 0):

Go to `General » Web » Session Cookie Management` and play around with the cookie settings and each of your store views.

If the store view is in a path change the `path` setting to the path of the store view. If it's in a subdomain, change the cookie domain setting to the subdomain of the store view.